# Outlook Notification sound only plays if Outlook is closed, but also arrives 30 min delayed

Tags: email, notifications

I am using Outlook on an Android phone. When I send an email to the phone:

- If Outlook is closed, the email will arrive up to 30 minutes later, accompanied by a Notification sound
- If Outlook is open, the email will arrive instantly, but WITHOUT any Notification sound

Is there a way to get my emails instantly, but also accompanied by a Notification sound? I am able to get this result on my desktop and laptop, just not working on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-change-mail-or-calendar-sounds-c894c2b7-f841-4ca5-a691-af595eb9f669

> ### How do I change mail or calendar sounds?
>
> To change mail or calendar sounds, tap Settings at the bottom right
> corner. Under Mail or Calendar tap Notifications, tap Sound, and then
> select the desired sound for Mail Notifications or Calendar
> Notifications.
>
> To turn off sounds, tap Sound, and then select Off.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/why-don-t-i-get-new-message-notifications-8f1b83d5-c3ac-409f-9dbb-83668d1b01b2

> ### Why don't I get new message notifications?
>
> By default, notifications will only appear for new messages in the
> Focused Inbox. If you want to be notified of all new messages:
>
> Within our app, tap Settings.
>
> Under Mail, tap Notifications.
>
> Change Mail Notifications per account to All, Focused Inbox Only, or
> None.
>
> You may also need to change your setting in the Android System for
> Notifications. This is different for each device, but please check
> that your system settings allow for Outlook to receive notifications.